# Let $[{\bf a} \times {\bf b} \space \; {\bf b} \times {\bf c}\space\; {\bf c} \times {\bf a} ]=k[{\bf a}\space{\bf b}\space{\bf c}]^2$. Find $k$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, determinant, cross-product

> Let $[{\bf a} \times {\bf b} \space \; {\bf b} \times {\bf c}\space\;  {\bf c} \times {\bf a} ]=k[{\bf a}\space{\bf b}\space{\bf c}]^2$. Find $k$.  Here, $[{\bf u}\ {\bf v} \ {\bf w}]={\bf u}\cdot({\bf v}\times {\bf w})$.

My attempt:

Writing scalar triple product as : $({\bf a} \times {\bf b}) \cdot \big(({\bf b} \times {\bf c}) \times ({\bf c}\times {\bf a})\big)$. Not able to proceed next.

Comment: Hint: $u \times (v \times w) = (u\cdot w) v - (u\cdot v) w$.
Substitute $(u,v,w)$ by $(b \times c, c, a)$, you get...

Comment: @achillehui I had thought the same way but I could not locate vector triple product.

Comment: @Ramit try this : https://m.imgur.com/a/H8ov3VR

Comment: There is one hidden within your scalar triple product: $$[a \times b, b \times c, c \times a]
= (a \times b) \cdot (\underbrace{(b \times c)}_u \times (\underbrace{c}_v \times \underbrace{a}_w))$$

Comment: @achillehui thanks. Got it!

Comment: @sai-kartik thanks. Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in a comment, we use the identity ${\bf u}\times({\bf v}\times {\bf w})=({\bf u}\cdot {\bf w}){\bf v}-({\bf u}\cdot {\bf v}){\bf w}$ (I proved it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606933/common-perpendicular-for-skew-lines/3609224#3609224)). Let $$\Delta={\bf a}\cdot({\bf b}\times {\bf c})={\bf b}\cdot({\bf c}\times {\bf a})={\bf c}\cdot({\bf a}\times {\bf b}).$$
 First we compute
$$({\bf b}\times {\bf c})\times ({\bf c}\times {\bf a})=\big(({\bf b}\times {\bf c})\cdot {\bf a}\big){\bf c}-\big(({\bf b}\times {\bf c})\cdot {\bf c}){\bf a}=\Delta {\bf c}-0{\bf a}=\Delta {\bf c}.$$
Therefore
$$({\bf a}\times {\bf b})\cdot\big(({\bf b}\times {\bf c})\times ({\bf c}\times {\bf a})\big)=({\bf a}\times {\bf b})\cdot \Delta {\bf c}=\Delta\big(({\bf a}\times {\bf b})\cdot {\bf c}\big)=\Delta^2.$$
Hence $k=1$.